# Give the delete button a confirmation prompt

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Is there a way to give the user a prompt window popup when clicking the remove field button?

enabling the remove button :

```
setCanRemoveRecords(true);
```

[image]

When I click the red remove button, I want a confirmation box ask me if I want to delete it, yes or no. What should I use to bring that up?

Should I be adding something into

```
  @Override
    public void removeData(Record group)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the options:

- Use `addCellClickHandler` on `ListGrid` and perform operation based on cell no
- Add `addRecordClickHandler` on `ListGridField` itself that is used for delete icon

I prefer last option.

**Sample code:**

```
    final ListGrid countryGrid = new ListGrid();
    ...

    countryGrid.setWarnOnRemoval(true);

    countryGrid.setCanRemoveRecords(true);
    ListGridField ls = new ListGridField();
    countryGrid.setRemoveFieldProperties(ls);
    ls.setHoverCustomizer(new HoverCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public String hoverHTML(Object value, ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum) {
            // System.out.println(colNum);
            return "click here to delete this record";
        }
    });

    ls.addRecordClickHandler(new RecordClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onRecordClick(final RecordClickEvent event) {
            SC.confirm("Are you sure?", new BooleanCallback() {

                @Override
                public void execute(Boolean value) {
                    if (value == null || !value) {
                        event.cancel();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });

    /*countryGrid.addCellClickHandler(new CellClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onCellClick(final CellClickEvent event) {
            // column number having delete icon
            // System.out.println(event.getColNum());
            if (event.getColNum() == 3) {
                SC.confirm("Are you sure", new BooleanCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void execute(Boolean value) {
                        if (value == null || !value) {
                            event.cancel();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following methods:

`ListGrid#setWarnOnRemoval` for showing the warning message and

`ListGrid#setWarnOnRemovalMessage` for setting a customized message.

[Refer documentation.](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html)